# count() for distinct values

Tags: sql, count, group-by, duplicates

Take the following example

```
CREATE TABLE #repeated ( iValue int NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #repeated
VALUES(1),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(5),(5),(6),(7)

SELECT * FROM #repeated

SELECT
    count(*) as countAsterisco
    ,count(iValue) as countValue
FROM #repeated
```

Both countAsterisco and countValue result in 10, because both counts consider duplicated values. I need to count only distinct values, so the result must be 7.

Is there a function for that? I thought `count(iValue)` would do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select count(distinct iValue) from #repeated
```